# Does mongodb have a VB.NET driver?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

Is there a tutorial on how to use VB.NET with mongodb?

It uses C#. However, I am used to VB.NET. Can the C# driver interact with VB.NET?

Comment: Does it provide a DLL? If it does, the language doesn't matter. If it only provides source, you can either compile that into a DLL yourself, or you can translate the C# to VB.NET using an online tool like [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) - most lines of C# can be directly translated to VB.NET and vice-versa.

Comment: let me check. I found a tutorial already on the web.

Comment: Have you tried [searching](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=mongodb+vb%23.net)?  There seem to be quite a few tutorials.  The .NET driver (which happens to be written in C#) should be usable in any .NET language.

Answer (score 1):

The C# driver will compile to a .NET DLL.

You should be able to add this DLL as a reference (like any other DLL) and use it from within VB.NET.